# What is the difference between a unicode and binary string?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I am in python3.3.

What is the difference between a unicode string and a binary string?

```
b'\\u4f60'
u'\x4f\x60'
b'\x4f\x60'
u'4f60'
```

The concept of Unicode and binary string is confusing.  How can i change `b'\\u4f60'`  into   `b'\x4f\x60'` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First - there is no difference between unicode literals and string literals in python 3.  They are one and the same - you can drop the `u` up front.  Just write strings.  So instantly you should see that the literal `u'4f60'` is just like writing actual `'4f60'`.

A `bytes` literal - aka `b'some literal'` - is a series of bytes.  Bytes between 32 and 127 (aka ASCII) can be displayed as their corresponding glyph, the rest are displayed as the `\x` escaped version.  Don't be confused by this - `b'\x61'` is the same as `b'a'`.  It's just a matter of printing.

A string literal is a string literal.  It can contain unicode codepoints.  There is far too much to cover to explain how unicode works here, but basically a codepoint represents a *glyph* (essentially, a *character* - a graphical representation of a letter/digit), it does not specify how the machine needs to represent it.  In fact there are a great many different ways.

Thus there is a very large difference between `bytes` literals and `str` literals.  The former describe the *machine representation*, the latter describe the alphanumeric glyphs that we are reading right now.  The mapping between the two domains is *encoding/decoding*.

I'm skipping over a lot of vital information here.  That should get us somewhere though.  I highly recommend [reading more](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) since this is not an easy topic.

---

> How can i change `b'\\u4f60'` into `b'\x4f\x60'` ?

Let's walk through it:

```
b'\u4f60'
Out[101]: b'\\u4f60' #note, unicode-escaped

b'\x4f\x60'
Out[102]: b'O`'

'\u4f60'
Out[103]: '你'
```

So, notice that `\u4f60` is that Han [ideograph](http://codepoints.net/U+4F60) glyph.  `\x4f\x60` is, if we represent it in ascii (or utf-8, actually), the letter O (`\x4f`) followed by backtick.

I can ask python to turn that unicode-escaped `bytes` sequence into a valid string with the according unicode glyph:

```
b'\\u4f60'.decode('unicode-escape')
Out[112]: '你'
```

So now all we need to do is to re-`encode` to bytes, right?  Well...

Coming around to what I *think* you're wanting to ask -

> How can i change  `'\\u4f60'` into its proper bytes representation?

There is no 'proper' bytes representation of that unicode codepoint.  There is only a representation in the encoding that you want.  It so happens that there is one encoding that directly matches the transformation to `b'\x4f\x60'` - [`utf-16be`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

```
b'\\u4f60'.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-16-be')
Out[47]: 'O`'
```

The reason this works is that `utf-16` is a variable-length encoding.  For code points below 16 bits it just directly uses the codepoint as the 2-byte encoding, and for points above it uses something called "surrogate pairs", which I won't get into.

Comment: think roippi,it can enhance my programming technics to transform b'\\u4f60' into b'\x4f\x60' ,how can i do ?

Comment: `b'\\u4f60'.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-16be') == b'\x4f\x60'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian well, I'll be (gah, didn't think about surrogate pairs).  Editing.

Comment: You could call Unicode codepoint "character". It is not precise but at least it provides some intuition. "glyph" might make it sounds more formal than it is. Concrete examples  of codepoints such as `'\u0061' == 'a'`, [`'\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER B}' == '\u0062' == 'b'`](http://codepoints.net/U+0062), and [`'\N{snowman}' == '\u2603' == '☃'`](http://codepoints.net/U+2603), or [`'\U0001F382' == '\N{BIRTHDAY CAKE}'`](http://codepoints.net/U+1F382) also might help.

Comment: Useful points.  I'll work on making this a little more layperson-friendly.